\urcorner for writting under it
I am trying to write the next equation into LaTeX

My biggest problem is about that "\urcorner" because I need to write inside the corner, and actually, all this type of corners will be always subindex, So I've used this
newcommand\newcommand{\overlinebar}[1]{\overline{#1} |}

This command works well for normal text, as shown in the following example:
\overlinebar{texto}

And this is my result:

I would like to improve what I have done, I have to use it many times within a document and I really don't know how to do it any other way, any suggestion is welcome. Thank you so much!

You want to use the actuarialangle package
